# Is it possible to attach an onclick event to specific coordinates in a document?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering if it is possible to attach an onclick event to specific coordinates in a document. Maybe something similiar to "area coords" in an image map that would allow me to create a rectangular or circular area that when clicked on would execute some code. Been trying to find a solution all morning hope someone with better coding knowledge could clarify this for me.

Comment: Why not just position a element (e.g. an absolute positioned div) and attaching an onclick on that?

Comment: When you say document, do you mean a page with HTML? Can you elaborate more on your situation?

Comment: @dtech: yeah I was doing that at first along with a setTimeout but the problem is that im trying to capture a click on an iframe on another domain so i figured that if I positioned the iframe then positioned an area of coordinates above the search button (im framing a search form) the user could submit a search and I could execute some code at the exact time they clicked on the search button. I'll probably just stick with the positioned div then, just curious to see if this was possible. . thanks everyone for the advice.

Answer (score 3):

You could attach a click event to the document itself as opposed to any specific element.  The event data should contain the coordinates of the mouse at the time of the click (clientX and clientY).

Assuming no other element intercepts and cancels propagation or returns false, the event should bubble up to the document and your data will be there for you.

```
$(document).click(function(ev){
    console.log(ev.clientX, ev.clientY)
})
```

That will give you the mouse pointer position in the window.  If you want it to be relative to the top of the document, you'll need to do some math using the scroll position of the document.

You could also write some code to filter out clicks that do or do not fall within a given set of coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **no**.

Long answer:

You could probably write a plugin to do this, but I'm just going to explain the functionality.

Basically, you bind to the click event, like usual. *Be sure that the element you bind to is reachable.*

Then, loop over an array of coordinates, and if the event position fell in any of the coordinates, called the associated event handler.

**Edit:** If it wasn't obvious, you can replace "a bunch of coordinates" with a function, or more precisely, a mathematical calculation. You could pass an equation to the handler which works with any kind of 2d shape you want.

Answer (score 0):

No, not unless you have an element that occupies these coordinates.  Instead, you could bind the event to whatever element occupies that coordinate space and simply check the coordinates of the click in the event object.